# iphone Custom Annotation callout showing in different location and it is moving when zooming into the map

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

started working on custom callout.I have created one custom callout with the image insted of annotation pin. when if it is a pin view it is showing proper location and pin sticked to one coordinate.

But in case of image annotation not showing properly and annotation is moving and it is showing wrongly.PLZ check the  below code and correct me. I stuck with it very badly i need the solution.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;

    self.map_View.delegate = self;

    [self createCustomAnnotation];
}

-(Void) createCustomAnnotation {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D locationCoordinate;
    locationCoordinate.latitude=37.300275;
    locationCoordinate.longitude=-121.640625;

    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 10;
    span.longitudeDelta = 10;

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = locationCoordinate;
    region.span =span;

    [self.map_View setRegion:region];

    MKPointAnnotation *pointAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
    pointAnnotation.title = @"a";
    pointAnnotation.coordinate = locationCoordinate;

    [self.map_View addAnnotation:pointAnnotation];
    [self.map_View selectAnnotation:pointAnnotation animated:YES];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv viewForAnnotation:(id      <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return nil;
    }

    static NSString *google = @"Pin";

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [_map_View dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:google];

    if (!annotationView) {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:google];
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"m.png"];
        annotationView. canShowCallout = YES;

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-20, -25, 70, 30)];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        label.text = @"DD";
        label. textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        [annotationView addSubview:labl];
    }
    else {
        // unrelated but should handle view re-use...
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;

        UILabel *label2 = (UILabel *)[annotationView viewWithTag:42];
        label2.text = annotation.title;

    }
    return annotationView;
}
```

If possible Provide me better solutions about Custom Callouts.

Answer (score 0):

below code working for me

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

Static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
MKAnnotationView* customPinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]
                               initWithAnnotation:annotation            reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];

 customPinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"m.png"];
customPinView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0.0f, -24.5(my image height/2)f);

return customPinView;
}
```